# Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting

Tags: node.js, callback, socket.io

Here I am facing one issue with Callbacks in socket.io with nodejs

```
io.sockets.to(usersocketid).emit('receivemsg', 
{'success':'1','data':message},function(deliverycb){ 
    console.log('delivery call back');
    console.log(deliverycb);
});
```

Where i am facing error of Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting so anyone have solution of this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using callback for acknowledgement,and according to socket.io documentation.

1. [Acknowledgements](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-to-room) are not supported when broadcasting.
2. [Acknowledgements](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args) are not supported when emitting from namespace.

I would say, if you need to send acknowledgement to the server, then emit another event from the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

First, get socket object from id, which you can refer to [Socket.IO 1.0.x: Get socket by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055989/socket-io-1-0-x-get-socket-by-id)

Then with the socket object, `socket.emit('type', 'message', ack =>{});`

Comment: iam using socket object, but when i add callback param, socket not send anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you were trying to emit the acknoledgement from the server side, without specifying the socket.id;

By the way, you can avoid that error, moving the acknowledgement request to the clint-side and just work the callback on the server-side.